# development server return response code: 500 react native debugger mode fails

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The exact error I get when I start the app is bundling failed:

> Error: Unable to resolve module `react-is` from 
>   `/Users/someguy/projects/third/some-app/node_modules/react-navigation/node_modules/react-native-tab-view/node_modules/prop-types/index.js`:
>   Module does not exist in the module map

The strange this about this error is that it only occurs when if I add

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.  This is needed due to the upgrade to SDK28.  If I build the app without

> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

I am able to start and run the app normally, but the metro bundler does NOT run and I can't access the debugger.

Should I add react-is to my package.json or do I just use npm and install it locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that by installing react-is.  Fixes the problem.